# "Operating system error 1394" - How can I prevent it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I get occasional and random failures of my SQL Server backups with the error message `Operating system error 1394`

**Does anyone know why this error occurs and how I can prevent it?**

A little Googling tells me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
ERROR_NO_USER_SESSION_KEY
1394 (0x572)
There is no user session key for the specified logon session.
```

Which is great... but does not tell me WHY this happens.

The SQL server backs up to a remote Windows network share on an Windows 2008 Server.  We run Active Directory.  There is a whole fleet of 50+ SQL Servers of different versions (2000,2005,2008,2008R2), running on Windows 2003, 2008 and 2008R2 *(Note to self: I really need to standardise!)*

Running the backup again does not reproduce the error.

**Full error message (redacted)**

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Backup failed for Server 'SQLSERVER'.
  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
  ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open backup device '\\BACKUPSERVER\backups\SQLSERVER\DATABASE_NAME\TRANSACTIONLOG_backup_20111118_104731.trnz'. Operating system error 1394(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.SqlBackup(Server srv)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.SqlBackup(Server srv)
   at SqlBackup(Object , Object[] )
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments).InnerException.message
```

Comment: Something similar has been "discussed" at [SQLServerCentral's forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1096952-357-1.aspx#bm1139974) a while ago. Not much of a resolution there, but at least you are not the only one with this problem.

Comment: @syneticon-dj : Thanks, I did see that! My 'huntch' is that it's to do with Active Directory authentication tickets that are being rejected - maybe because of a time sync issue between the servers. But this is just a guess and I'd like something to back that up...

Comment: I do not think this is (directly) kerberos-related. This would be rather something about the SMB session to the destination's server share. Can't you back up locally and copy the backup files after this as a workaround?

Comment: @syneticon-dj : 50+ SQL instances and several hundred databases and in the middle of the night?  I need my beauty sleep mate!
It seems to be a temporary glitch thing, and my script will just try again in 10 minutes or so.  But I do get error message emails for every fail and, well, I shouldn't be getting these errors!